# Exchange - listing mailboxes in an OU with their mailbox size

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to display all the mailboxes and their sizes for all our users in our Departed OU. I seem to be very close but my command seems to be adding some padding to the results.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>dsquery user "ou=Departed,ou=Staff,dc=COMPANY,dc=local" -limit 4 | dsget user -samid | Get-MailboxStatistics | ft DisplayName, TotalItemSize, ItemCount
```

And the output:

```
Dsquery has reached the specified limit on number of results to display; use a different value for the -limit option to
display more results.The specified mailbox "  samid                 " doesn't exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Get-MailboxStatistics], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DD7D7CEA,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.MapiTasks.GetMailboxStatistics

The specified mailbox "  Eka.Tian              " doesn't exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (1:Int32) [Get-MailboxStatistics], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 7F701DFD,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.MapiTasks.GetMailboxStatistics
```

Obviously shouldnt work for the first result "samid" but "Eka.Tian" exists. Why is it adding all those spaces? Is there a way I could format the output from dsget user so it plays nice with Get-MailboxStatistics?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why the dsquery?

```
get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "ou=Departed,ou=Staff,dc=COMPANY,dc=local" -resultsize unlimited |
 get-mailboxstatistics | ft DisplayName,TotalItemSize,Itemcount
```

Comment: oh my :)
I did not see the -organizationunit switch. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I've got something for you, even though it's a little late.
You just need to adjust every Searchbase with OU and DC, the Email-Adresses at the end and the SMTP-Server, then you get an Email with a CSV-Attachment that contains every OU with Counts of active and inactive Mailboxes and a list with every mailbox and its parameters.
You can also trigger it with the Task-Scheduler of Windows, so it's an automatic report.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.SnapIn;
$Kunden=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Kunden,DC=domain,DC=domain"
$leerzeile ="`n"

#Funktion für 10 GB Kontrolle
function getUber10 ($name)
{
$Uberschreit=0
$anzahluber10=0
$anzahl=0
$UserList = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "$name" |Get-MailboxStatistics
$großen = $UserList |Select TotalItemSize
for($y=0; $y -lt $großen.Length; $y++){
if($großen[$y].totalItemSize.value.toMB() -gt 10000){
$wieoft=$großen[$y].totalItemSize.value.toMB() * 0.0001
$anzahluber10 = $anzahluber10 +  [Math]::Ceiling($wieoft) - 1
}
}
$anzahluber10
}

#Liste aller Kunden mit Postfachanzahl
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Kunden, DC=domain, DC=domain" |Select-Object Name, @{n="Postfach-Anzahl";e = {(Get-ADUser -Filter {(EmailAddress -like "*@*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -SearchBase $_).count}},`
@{n="Deaktivierte Postfächer";e = {(Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "False"} -SearchBase $_).count}}, @{n="10GB-Überschreitungen"; e={ getUber10 -name $_}} `
| ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-File C:\ExchangeReport.csv -Append

$leerzeile | Out-File C:\ExchangeReport.csv -Append
$leerzeile | Out-File C:\ExchangeReport.csv -Append

#Liste der einzelnen Kunden mit Details der Postfächer
For($i=1; $i -lt $Kunden.Length; $i++){
$Kunde=$Kunden[$i]
$Uberschreit=0
$anzahluber10=0
$anzahl=0
$UserList = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "$Kunde" |Get-MailboxStatistics
$großen = $UserList |Select TotalItemSize
for($x=0; $x -lt $großen.Length; $x++){
if($großen[$x].totalItemSize.value.toMB() -gt 10000){
$wieoft=$großen[$x].totalItemSize.value.toMB() * 0.0001
$anzahluber10 = $anzahluber10 +  [Math]::Ceiling($wieoft) - 1
}
}

Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $Kunden[$i] |Select-Object Name, @{n="Postfach-Anzahl";e = {(Get-ADUser -Filter {(EmailAddress -like "*@*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -SearchBase $Kunde).count}}`
,@{n="Deaktivierte Postfächer";e = {(Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "False"} -SearchBase $_).count}},@{n="10GB-Überschreitungen"; e={$uberschreit= $anzahluber10 ; $uberschreit}}`
| ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-File C:\ExchangeReport.csv -Append

Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "$Kunde" |Select-Object @{n="Kundenname";e={Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $Kunden[$i] |Select-Object Name}}, Displayname, PrimarySmtpAddress, `
@{n="Size(MB)";e = {$Fachstat = Get-MailboxStatistics $_.name;$Fachstat.totalItemsize.value.toMB()}}, @{n="Quota";e={$Fachquot=Get-Mailbox $_.name;$Fachquot.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota}},`
 @{n="Aktiv?"; e={Get-ADUser $_.DistinguishedName |select Enabled}}, @{n="Über 10GB?"; e={$uber10 = Get-MailboxStatistics $_.name; if($uber10.totalItemSize.value.toMB() -gt 10000){$uber10.IsValid}else{$uber10.IsQuarantined}}} `
 | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')} | % {$_.Replace('@{Name=','')} | % {$_.Replace('}','')} | % {$_.Replace('@{Enabled=','')} | Out-File C:\ExchangeReport.csv -Append

$leerzeile | Out-File C:\ExchangeReport.csv -Append
$leerzeile | Out-File C:\ExchangeReport.csv -Append
}

$Date = Get-DAte -UFormat "%d.%m.%Y"
Send-MailMessage -to "empfänger@domain.domain" -from "administrator@domain.domain" -Subject "Exchange-Report" -body "Exchange Report of $Date" -SmtpServer "External IP" -Attachments "C:\ExchangeReport.csv"
Remove-Item C:\ExchangeReport.csv
```

I wrote the variables etc. in German, I hope thats no problem ;)